# Invite users to Google Play using a service account

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to write a CI/CD script that will automatically invite new users to an existing Google Play Console developer account.

I have tried to use Android Publisher API's `users.create` method, using a token generated by `gcloud auth print-access-token SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL` after authenticating with the service account credentials in the GCP CLI.

But for some reason, I get the following error message when trying to do it using this REST API request `https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/developers/MY_DEV_ID/users`:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "method": "google.play.publishingapi.v3.AccessService.ListUsers",
                    "service": "androidpublisher.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tried to find a way to enable the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher` scope in the service account, but couldn't find any way.

Does any one know what would be the best way to invite new users to the Google Play Console using a CLI/REST API call?

Thank you

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: This is a [similar case](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Anthos/403-Error-when-trying-to-initialize-a-project-for-Anthos-Service/m-p/168964#M1) in GCC, have you taken a look at it? It seems you're missing some steps.